# Alternative to this python code?

Tags: python, sorting, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I have a line of code from class that I don't understand fully and want some easier alternative to. What this does is , uses weightList, which is a list of edges that's connected to each other, and returns the edgelists with lowest corresponding value from the graph (adjacency matrix). This is for a Prim's Minimum Spanning Tree problem.

`edge = sorted(weightList, key=lambda e:graph[e[0]][e[1]])[0];`

Comment: It's great that you now understand that line, but it might be worth saying it isn't a particularly efficient way of doing it. You should use `min` instead of `sorted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking it up a little bit could be enough. How about this?

```
get_edge_weight = lambda e: graph[e[0]][e[1]]
sorted_weights = sorted(weightList, key=get_edge_weight)
edge = sorted_weights[0]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The code makes sense now.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as you said: for all edges, find the value in the graph which is the lowest.

```
i, j = current_edge = weightList[0]
current_min = graph[i][j]

for edge in weightList[1:]:
    i, j = edge

    if graph[i][j] < current_min:
        current_min = graph[i][j]
        current_edge = edge
```

You start with the first edge from your `weightList`, then you iterate on all other edges to try and find a value which is lower. When you exit the loop, `current_edge` is the edge with the lowest value.

That being said, it might be worth instead to try and understand your code. I assume you know what [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) does. To sort your `weightList`, [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) uses the parameter `key`, which is a function that returns a value. In your case, your function returns the value in `graph` at the position of your edge. [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) will use this value to compare the edges together.

Thus, this will sort all your edges from the one with the lowest value to the one with the highest value. Then, once it is sorted, you take the first element, which is the edge with the lowest value.

Algorithmically, using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) for this job isn't a great idea since it has a time complexity of `O(n log n)`. In comparison, my algorithm is `O(n)` (but probably slower because I assume `sorted` is implemented in C). Instead, you can obtain the same result in `O(n)` using standard functions by using [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), which certainly is the most efficient and readable option out of all three:

```
edge = min(weightList, key=lambda (i,j): graph[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to be a little less "compact", this should do the trick:

```
shortest = weightList[0]

for edge in weightList:
    if graph[edge[0]][edge[1]] < graph[shortest[0]][shortest[1]]:
        shortest = edge
```

Set the shortest edge to be equal to the first edge in the weightList, then go through the list and see if any edges are shorter.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to reduce complexity, I always look for ways to break things out into self explanatory, modular functions:

```
def distance(adjacency_matrix, start_node, end_node):
    return adjacency_matrix[start_node][end_node]

sorted_edges = sorted(weightList, key=lambda e: distance(graph, e[0], e[1]))
edge = sorted_edges[0];
```